# xamarin studio created ad hoc iPhone app doesn't show developer in iTunes

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin

I have created my first iPhone app using xamarin forms and have successfully deployed it to several iPhones.  The problem is when I select Get Info in iTunes the developer field is empty.  The title and version display correctly, but the developer field is blank.  I have populated the Author Information in the solution options, but I'm wondering if I have to populate a similar field in the iIOS options dialog?  Thank you.

Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not something that is specified in your iOS App project. The developer information shown on iTunes/AppStore is part of your Apple developer account information in iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used iTunes connect,  I'm not even sure what is yet. My app was built using an adhoc distribution profile. Perhaps that information doesn't get filled in until I officially publish the app, would that be a correct assumption?

Thanks